# How to fix apt update,upgrade

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux, gnu-screen

Due to new installation an error was show that installation step failed
Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-last-snapshot/inrelease Temporary resolving'http.kali.org'

Comment: OK is http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/kali/dists/kali-last-snapshot/InRelease   ..... and http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-last-snapshot/InRelease  ..... but **not** your misspelled  http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-last-snapshot/inrelease

Answer (score 1):

Use a mirror to solve the `Temporary resolving'http.kali.org'` error, see https://http.kali.org/README.mirrorlist.

```
echo "deb https://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main contrib non-free" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Nit pick, you don't need a backslash line continuation character if the last character on the line would be a pipe. Strange but true. Nevertheless +1